# Microsoft Graph API: Get all rules for mail account

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I have and admin account in Office365 with an app that's been given full access to anything exchange related. I am writing an app that has a use case where I would need to get all the Rules created in a user's mailbox. This would include things like the the rule name, the contents etc.

This would ideally include things like Active Sync settings between devices, permissions to eDiscovery mailboxes etc.

I do not see support for those in the graph API. Is there a way to get this information?

Comment: Is this for a web addin?

Comment: no - this is for an Azure AD multi tenant app

Comment: What do you want to achieve by using `Microsoft graph`? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for those advanced things in the Microsoft Graph API. You need to use Exchange Web Services (EWS) for it.

For instance [you can retrieve eDiscover information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj190897(v=exchg.150).aspx) and you can manage the [manage inbox rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn481313(v=exchg.150).aspx) also. Check out the [full reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data(v=exchg.80).aspx) of the EWS Managed API for a long list of things you can do.

You can use Azure AD OAuth 2.0 authentication to authorize access to EWS in Office 365 by adding the Bearer token to EWS requests.

Comment: Thanks - but EWS itself lacks support in some of those settings I would need. Basically I am looking for something that would give me all the data that's available in Exchange Admin Center either in the form of an event stream or an API. EWS is feature rich but given microsoft's lack of support and the performance of those requests in a REST/microservice oriented architecture - it does not fit in well.